# Question on division and remainder

Tags: divisor-sum

How to solve these type of questions?

> Which of the following  numbers must be added to $5678$ to give a
>   remainder of $35$ when divided by $460$?(Options are)

```
A) 618
B) 955
C) 797
D) 980
```

This is an aptitude question.

Comment: Maybe note first that the remainder when we divide our big number by $460$ is $158$. Then the $7$ that ends C) is a giveaway.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes I noticed it, but now how can I use it? Can you explain more?

Comment: We have an $8$ at the end of the remainder, so we need to add something that ends in $7$ to get a remainder that ends in $5$.

Comment: There are *many* ways to go about solving such a question, but a viable approach should be one that *you* understand. Can you give us more information about your thoughts on the problem, and what you've tried so far? That will help us to tailor our answers to your needs.

Comment: I was watching the remainder after dividing the  5678 by 460 and then trying to find out a way using this remainder @CameronBuie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task is to solve $5678+n\equiv 35\ (\text{mod}\ 460)$.

If you don't have a calculator, I'd first note that you can subtract $4600$ from the $5678$ to get

$1078+n\equiv 35$

then subtract another $2\cdot460=920$:

$158+n\equiv 35$

For this to be true we need something like $158+n=495$. Solve to get $n=337$. This isn't an option so add another 460.

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice explanation.